# Waypoint and Inview jquery. How to Fix DOM Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to customize a wordpress plugin called wp post listing. I want to target the #basic-waypoint-cyberwrath that wraps the load more button because the plugin doesn't have an automation. It needs to manually click the load more button in which I don't like it.

This is the code that I have got so far for inview:

```
var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
    element : $('#basic-waypoint-cyberwrath')[0],
    enter : function(direction) {
        //alert('Enter triggered with direction ' + direction)
    },
    entered : function(direction) {
        //alert('Entered triggered with direction ' + direction)
        $('.wpp_loadmore_pager').click();
    },
    exit : function(direction) {
        //alert('Exit triggered with direction ' + direction)
    },
    exited : function(direction) {
        //alert('Exited triggered with direction ' + direction)
    }
});
```

When I use the alert function. It alerts very well in inview no matter how many times I scrolled to the ID. It keeps firing the alert function. But when I used the click function. It only fire once because the #basic-waypoint-cyberwrath was newly dynamically loaded each time when you click the load more button. This is the closest code that I have done so far. .

And this is the code that I got so far for waypoint:

```
var $fusionheader = $('#basic-waypoint-cyberwrath');
$fusionheader.waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        // do stuff
        //alert('I am going down');
        $('.wpp_loadmore_pager').click();
    }
    jQuery.waypoints('refresh');
}, {
    offset : '90%'
});
```

I already tried almost everything. I dont know anymore what am I missing here.
Both are good when scrolling down for the first time and then triggers when it sees the #basic-waypoint-cyberwrath but it doesn't trigger anymore for round 2 and so on the load more button in order to see the other post listings.

I even tried a for loop statement but still no luck:

```
var discreteElements = document.getElementById('basic-waypoint-cyberwrath');
for (var i = 0; i < discreteElements.length; i++) {
    new Waypoint.Inview({
        element : this,
        enter : function(direction) {
        },
        entered : function(direction) {
            //animatelettering.textillate('in')
            $('.wpp_loadmore_pager').click();
        },
        exit : function(direction) {
            //animatelettering.textillate('out')
        },
        exited : function(direction) {
        }
    });
};
```

Please help.

Comment: This sounds to me like a DOM issue. Most likely `.wpp_loadmore_pager` is getting added dynamically after scrolling, so `.click()` only affects the original DOM element.  What happens (or is supposed to happen) when `.wpp_loadmore_pager` is clicked?  Also, can you manually click that element and if so, does it work?

Comment: Yes it work John. 

About the DOM Issue. Oh I see. I didn't know. I guess that's the problem.

Any solution for that? And you are right. The wpp_loadmore_pager  does loaded dynamically in infinite scrolling

Comment: @johnniebenson When you click the .wpp_loadmore_pager. It will disappear and a loading icon will show up. It will load the other 10 post listings and then a new .wpp_loadmore_pager button will show up after it loaded the 10 post listings.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to track down what is actually causing the loading of those posts (probably a function) and re-attach the handler to the click event there. You can accomplish this by using

```
$(".container").on("click", ".wpp_loadmore_pager", function() {
    //load_function();
});
```

Most likely `.wpp_loadmore_pager` has a click event attached to it somewhere and it's running some function (load_posts(), get_posts(), etc). In that function you'll probably see the code which recreates that button. That is where you'll need to reattach the handler.

Comment: Hi Johnniebenson, thanks for the help but I'm not sure if you understand what I needed. Just to be more clear and see if we are in the same page. Check this video:
http://cyberwrathinternetmarketing.com/graphicdesigns/infinite-scroll.wmv

Comment: As you can see. The wordpress plugin that has an infinite scroll still requires to manually click the load more button but I don't like that kind of concept. Using my custom codes. When I scrolled down and hits the target ID using waypoint and inview. I was able to automate the click event on the button. But on the second scrolled down. The automate click didn't work. That is where the DOM issue starts in which I need to fix it.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your on() jquery is the solution for this kind of automation click? I think your suggestion about on() still requires to manually click it? In which it must not need to do the manual click.

It should be click automatically when it scrolled down to the target ID basic-waypoint-cyberwrath. Once this code is working perfectly. I will be able to hide the load more button permanently. Just like in newsroom.uber.com That is my ultimate goal. :)

Comment: When you use `.click()` without a handler, you are _triggering_ a click event.  This is the same as using your mouse to click something.  If you pass a handler `.click(function() { ... })` you are binding that handler to the click event.  This is like saying "run this code if this element ever gets clicked."  The issue is that dynamically added elements (your new buttons) do not have anything bound to them because they are created _after_ the DOM is loaded.  This is where `.on()` comes in handy.  You can attached the handler to a parent element and apply it to specific selectors.

Comment: That being said, my suggestion of using `.on()` would allow you to continue to use `$(".wpp_loadmore_pager").click()` on all future clones of that button, which is what I thought was your original intent.  It now occurs to me that instead of using `.click()` to _trigger_ a click, you could replace it with the function to show the next page of data.  That should work for you and would help get rid of the troublesome dynamic buttons and forcing of clicks.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll see what I can do there using your code above. Will let you know if it works! :)